# How to find Euclidean Norm of rows of a matrix with BLAS?

Tags: matrix, blas, euclidean-distance

I have an matrix M that I need to calculate its Euclidean Norm of its rows. Is it possible to use the efficiency of BLAS library for such purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can apply one of the `NRM2` family of functions to each row separately.

Comment: @Erogol No I don't think there is any single function call to compute this for all rows.